# How to set "new tab button" in uitabgroup/GUI Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

is there a way to set pushbutton to create new empty tab in Matlab GUI (like "new tab" button in Chrome or Firefox browser?)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaFTm.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity - what are you planning to do with this new tab? Create elements programmatically? Also, are you using "old" figures, or "new" **ui**figures?

Comment: I have several tab that describe some physical object. I want to add new object interactively from the GUI, once the GUI is done. I'm using old figure